# pandas dataframe group columns based on name and apply a function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-munging

I have a dataframe:

```
df = [A   B   C   D  E_p0   E_p1   E_p2    K_p0  K_p1  K_2  
      a   2   r   4   3       6     1       9     5     1
      e   g   1   d   5       8     2       7     1     4]
```

And I want to group columns based on the prefix and aggregate them by a function, such as mean or max or rms.
So, for example if my function is max, the output is:

```
df = [A   B   C   D   E    K  
      a   2   r   4   6    9  
      e   g   1   d   8    7   ]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GroupBy columns on column header prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54207038/groupby-columns-on-column-header-prefix)

Comment: @dm2 It's looks OK, only it limits me to predefined agg function (e.g. sum()) , how can I groupby and then apply custom aggregation function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert columns without separator to index and then grouping with lambda function per columns with aggregate function like `max`:

```
m = df.columns.str.contains('_')

df = (df.set_index(df.columns[~m].tolist())
        .groupby(lambda x: x.split('_')[0], axis=1)
        .max()
        .reset_index())
print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  K
0  a  2  r  4  6  9
1  e  g  1  d  8  7
```

Solution with custom function:

```
def rms(x):
    return np.sqrt(np.sum(x**2, axis=1)/len(x.columns))

m = df.columns.str.contains('_')

df1 = (df.set_index(df.columns[~m].tolist())
        .groupby(lambda x: x.split('_')[0], axis=1)
        .agg(rms)
        .reset_index())
print (df1)
   A  B  C  D         E         K
0  a  2  r  4  3.915780  5.972158
1  e  g  1  d  5.567764  4.690416
```

Comment: Thanks, and if I want a custom function instead of max (e.g. RMS)?

Comment: @okuoub - Added to answer.